# Fuzzy pdf output in the viewer of texmaker (Yosemite OSx)

Tags: pdf

I have started using tex maker on the Macbook Pro (retina display). And the internal pdf viewer makes shows very low resolution pdf output. While no issue if I look directly via Adobe reader. Does anyone know how to fix this? [image]

Comment: There is a known bug in PDFkit on Yosemite - see [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152492/font-smoothing-for-pdf-files-in-osx-yosemite-safari-vs-skim) over on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I read the question but it doesn't seem to offer a solution. Any updates on this?